# Breeze rejectChanges() doesn't return a promise?

Tags: angularjs, breeze

With the following code:

```
function cancelChanges() {
    if (datacontext.manager.hasChanges()) {
        return datacontext.manager.rejectChanges();
    } else {
        console.log("No changes to save");
    }
}
```

If I call it like this:

```
         cancelChanges()
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("Changes Cancelled");
                })
```

I get "Object has no method 'then'".  If I use `saveChanges`, it works.  Another problem with this is that the `else` statement is not returning anything so I'll get an error with the `.then` and `.fail` calls... how can this be fixed to use promises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a promise of your own using the `$q` service in angular.

```
 function cancelChanges() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (datacontext.manager.hasChanges()) {
        datacontext.manager.rejectChanges();
        deferred.resolve("Changes Cancelled");
    } else {
        deferred.reject("No changes to save");
    }
    return deferred.promise;
 }

    cancelChanges()
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            })
```

Comment: Thanks for this - any idea why .then would work off of the deferred.promise, but .fail wouldn't?  I'm getting a "no such method" for fail, but then is working.

Comment: The promise returned does not have a `success` or `fail` method. You can achieve the same end with `then`. `.then(function(result){ // success }, function(result){ // failed})`

Comment: You have just discovered one of the ways that Angular's $q differs from the richer API of Q.js

Answer (score 3):

Breeze only returns promises for asynchronous methods. **This is by design**.  But as another poster has pointed out you can always construct a promise from an already realized result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly more economical syntax for `cancelChanges` then Jonathan Palumbo (who has the right idea) proposed:

```
 function cancelChanges() {
    if (datacontext.manager.hasChanges()) {
        datacontext.manager.rejectChanges();
        return $q.when("Changes Cancelled");
    } 
    return $q.reject("No changes to save");
 }
```

See [API documentation for $q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q).

P.S.: I'm somewhat mystified why you want the method to fail when there are no changes to cancel rather than return the success path for that as well. And I can't understand why this is an async method. I guess you have your reasons.